# run shell script in one line from applescript and provide input

Tags: macos, applescript, macos-sierra

I'm trying to automate the installation of a program that needs to be run from the Terminal on MacOS. This seems simple enough but the installation script expects needs to run as root (or sudo) and find files from the root directory that it's running from and then looks for the user to provide a password as terminal input before it completes. I don't mind providing the password in a readable format as we will only be using it internally and the password will be changed soon after we're finished with this project.

I have the following so far and it's not working because it doesn't seem to accept my input from the response file. I'm using the sleep to wait the few moments that it takes to execute that first step.

```
do shell script "cd ~/Desktop/; ./setup; /bin/sleep 5; ~/Desktop/MyApp/Tools/RunThis_WithVarialbles -s blah.com -someOtherVaiable -u uName@blah.com < ~/Desktop/sccm/Tools/response.txt" password "passwdIDCisVisible`enter code here`" with administrator privileges
```

The error I get from Script Editor is:

```
error "/bin/sh: ./setup: No such file or directory
ERROR 2 when mkdir in CreateDirectory - No such file or directoryERROR 2 when mkdir in CreateDirectory - No such file or directory
Please enter your password.
(null)(null)(null)(null)(null)" number 8
```

I'll be the first to admit that I'm a total Noob! Thanks for your patience!

Comment: The problem is likely in `./setup`, so you probably should post the code for that.

Comment: ./setup is an executable binary supplied by a vendor.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I can see a couple of wrongs in your command already. And it still seems pretty unclear what you are trying to achieve. Yet, instead of asking a lot of questions and causing confusion, let's just stick to the first step.

The first part of your error message reads: `error "/bin/sh: ./setup: No such file or directory`. So this could indicate that:

1. ~/Desktop/setup does not exist. (Check if it does).
2. ~/Desktop/setup is not properly specified and you need to add a file extensions (e.g. like ~/Desktop/setup.sh)
3. You do not have the proper rights to execute the file. So you should execute something like `chmod u+x` to give execution rights to your current user. (And `sudo chmod u+x` for root).

See if you can get passed that first. Learning to code usually means taking baby steps at first.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Please see my responses to yours below...

1. ~/Desktop/setup does exist, it's a binary compiled by the software vendor, it's not a script that I can edit. Yes, I verified that it's a binary as strange as it may sound.

2. ~/Desktop/setup has no extension.

3. It's already executable.

Comment: Ok, but then 2 questions remain: how have you determined that is executable? Could you post the output of `ls -l` so we can know for sure? Also, if it is a binary it will never run if you do not specify a specific program to run it with. In your current command you are trying to run it as a regular shell script, which won't work since regular shells like BASH and ZSH will not be able to execute it by themselves.